# Laravel debug inside helpers shows me \App\User class not found

Tags: laravel, debugging, xdebug

I'm trying my first debug in Laravel using Xdebug and when I set the breakpoint and try to step over when `\App\User` model is calling it shows me class not found error which I attached in the below image:

[image]

this is my launch.json file below

```
{
"version":"0.2.0",
"configurations": [        
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/opt/lampp/htdocs/investproTheme": "${workspaceRoot}",
            },
            // add this
            "ignore": [
                "**/vendor/**/*.php"
            ],
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9001
    }

] }
```

Comment: not sure what your question is, but apparently that class doesn't exist ...?

Comment: What version of Laravel? Newer versions store models in the `app\Models` folder

Comment: What file and most importantly **how** are you debugging this? What config/commands do you use. Based on the screenshot, _it looks to me_ that you are trying to debug `helpers.php` file **directly**. If I'm correct ... then it is wrong because because you are bypassing the whole Laravel framework bootstrap code including class autoloading code that is responsible for class autoloading (at very least this can explain such error).

Comment: @LazyOne yes i am doing directly to helpers.php so its wrong so i have to try in controller class ?

Comment: @PawanManka If you will try to debug your controller class in the same way... you will then see a similar error as well. Seems to me that you may not have an understanding of the lifecycle of the Laravel (how it works; how the request gets handled). You place breakpoints where you need them ... but you need to debug/execute the whole request so all important parts of the Laravel framework lifecycle will be executed/involved.

Comment: @PawanManka What are you trying to debug -- a web request (a web page / URL) or a CLI command (e.g. `php artisan something`)? You need to use `Listen for XDebug` config (but make sure that Xdebug/VSCode are configured properly -- the port number in particular -- it's different in your configs). For a web page debug you also need to use Xdebug browser extension that when active will set an Xdebug cookie that will act as a "debug me" flag. Or you need to configure your Xdebug (php.ini) so it tries to debug _every single request_ regardless of such "debug me" flag.

Comment: @LazyOne can you share me any link or tutorial for XDebug in laravel . i  am trying first time and yeah i am trying to  debug a web request (a web page / URL)

Answer (score 2):

**If you are using Laravel 8 or 9**, you are wrongly referencing the User Model so try this:

```php
// In the first lines of your file
use \App\Models\User;

...

User::find($usr); // Call this way on line 310

-- OR --

\App\Models\User::find($usr);
```

**Also remember to replace all `\App\User` calls with suggested way!**

#### Re-run composer auto-loader

Sometimes composer don't track some clases so the auto loader wont get them to work, in that case try this in the console:

`composer dump-autoload`

Comment: (Assuming they're on Laravel 9. In earlier versions, it was `App\User`. I think you're right here, but important to note that many tutorial may accurately say `App\User` as they were written with earlier versions of Laravel.)

Comment: You are right, I assumed he is using laravel 8 or 9 by default. I will correct!

Comment: `use` takes backslashes

Comment: @Guille i am using laravel  "laravel/framework": "^7.0",

Comment: try the command `php artisan optimize:clear` this will clear all generated cache from laravel maybe that can help!